# Symmetric and Asymmetric ciphers, non-repudiation?

Tags: encryption

I have read on wikipedia "**However, symmetric ciphers also can be used for non-repudiation purposes** by ISO 13888-2 standard."

Then again and I read on another wiki page, "Non-repudiation, or more specifically non-repudiation of origin, is an important aspect of digital signatures. By this property an entity that has signed some information cannot at a later time deny having signed it. Similarly, access to the public key only does not enable a fraudulent party to fake a valid signature. **This is in contrast to symmetric systems, where both sender and receiver share the same secret key, and thus in a dispute a third party cannot determine which entity was the true source of the information.**"

This means one page says symmetric algorithms have non-repudiation and another page says they don't have it and therefore they are not used for digital signatures. So do symmetric keys have non-repudiation or not? It makes sense that they can not be used for signatures and non-repudiation since symmetric keys are the same and thus the system can't distinguish which one belongs to which person and which one is first etc. In that case I think symmetric keys are only a tool for confidentiality and not used for non-repudiation or digital signatures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer depends on whether the shared key is public or not. If the parties agree to public source (third party) for their shared key there is non-repudiation of origin.

Comment: If it's a secret key cryptosystem (not a public key) and they share the same key? Then they have non-repudiation and they can be used for digital signatures even though it's a symmetric key?  (because it's not public?)

Comment: Remember that asymmetric codes use different keys for encrypting and decrypting messages. This is “public key” encryption, a public key is available to anyone who can use it to encrypt a message. But only those with a private key can decrypt the messages and this, of course, is kept secret. Non repudiation is that anyone can use the "public key" and without a third party escrow.

Answer (score 3):

As for **non-repudiation**, the tricky part is that it's not technical but rather legal term and it causes a lot of misunderstanding if placed in technical context. The thing is that **you can always repudiate anything** you have done. And that's why there are courts.

In the court two parties are confronted and try to prove each other wrong using **evidence**. Here's where technology comes, as it allows to collect sufficient electronic evidence to prove wrong the party that tries to deny a transaction, message etc.

And this is exactly what ISO 13888 series does in part 1: it provides guidelines on what evidence to collect and how to protect it to maximise your chances of countering a repudiation of electronic transaction. This standard talks about a number of **tokens** that serve this purpose. These tokens are for example: identifiers of both parties, timestamps, message hashes etc. Then it goes into details on how you should protect these tokens so that they retain their value as evidence.

The two other parts (2 and 3) describe specific cryptographic techniques that can be applied to obtain tokens. Symmetric ones are just keyed hashes if I remember correctly (such as HMAC), while assymetric is digital signature.

Answer (score 1):

ISO 13888-2 introduces structures and protocols which can be used to introduce non-repudiation services, in the context of symmetric techniques.   However all these "tricks" rely on the existence of a Trusted Third Party.

The point of the second Wikipedia citation in the question is that asymmetric key systems *intrinsically* [and without the need of thrid parties] offer non-repudiation features  (specifically NRO i.e. non-repudation of the the Origin).

Comment: So I guess it really depends on the third party. Thanks!